# Select all songs as compilations

Tags: itunes

How do I select all songs as compilations in my iTunes. I don't want to modify each song one at a time, I have about 2000 songs.

Answer (score 2):

Command+A -> Command+I -> Options -> Part of Compilation -> Yes -> OK

Not sure why you'd want to do this and I didn't test it because I don't want to do this to my library but that should be it.